# How to configure New Relic for Spring boot Backend Code

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, newrelic

I am working on a task to configure new relic So that we can monitor our services (Rest Services). I have idea how to do that with frontend code as we can include new relic js code in common js file but In my case it's Spring boot application and we are using Gradle to build it.

I tried to search out the way on google but didn' find out.Can anybody please suggest the way to do it or share some link.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.kubrynski.com/2014/12/include-java-agent-in-standalone-spring.html it uses maven but you should be able to replicate the procedure with gradle.

Comment: @PärNilsson Yes I have. I have added the dependency and jar is newrelic-api.jar is there but here onwards i am not able to relate my gradle project with the given post.